# Are firewalls required if using a VPN

Tags: firewalls, vpn

If you are using a VPN to transmit data from router to router, do you still need a firewall?

I am using a VPN Server to encapsulate data from one cisco router to another. Do I need to have a firewall in front of each of the routers?

If I do, do I still need a firewall if I am using a Cisco VPN Server with inbuilt firewall functionality?

Comment: http://www.ebay.com/gds/Everything-You-Need-to-Know-About-Firewalls-and-VPN-Devices-/10000000177629217/g.html this might help u

Comment: Define "required". A firewall is never required, in the sense that your Internet access will work without one. It's also usually possible to configure a system such that it doesn't need a separate firewall to block potential threats. In fact, in an ideal world, firewalls wouldn't exist.

Comment: What's your threat model? What assets are you protecting?  Please read [the page explaining what is on-topic](http://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  As that page explains, "What background should I give in my question?  Security is a very contextual topic: threats that are deemed important in your environment may be inconsequential in somebody else's, and vice versa. [..] To get the most helpful answers you should tell us: [...see the page for the list...]"  You didn't tell us any of that.

Comment: Great, thanks D.W. This will greatly improve my questions/answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While reading around this topic found two intresting answers :

From [cisco Forums :](https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/9709676/firewall-needed-ip-vpn)

> An IPSec VPN only provides protection for the traffic that is being
>   transmitted through the VPN. It provides no protection about any other
>   traffic that might be received. I have deployed many VPN routers where
>   we provide protection against other traffic. I am surprised some times
>   at the amount of other traffic, which includes probes of the network
>   and things that are likely attack attempts, which we detect and
>   discard at the edge of the remote network.
>
> Depending on how the VPN is terminated (on an Internet facing router,
>   or a concentrator or other device behind the edge of the remote
>   network) the firewall might be positioned between the VPN termination
>   and the remote network in which case it will see the all of the
>   traffic and be able to evaluate it. Or the firewall might be between
>   the VPN termination and the remote network edge in which case it will
>   see the IPSec traffic but not be able to evaluate it while it can
>   evaluate all other traffic.

And also view this :

VPN Behind firewall :

[image]

**VPN Server Behind the Firewall on the Internet**
[image]

Image credit : Technet forums

Comment: If you don't forget "the inside enemy", any VPN server should be protected on both sides. Or if you prefer, my advice is that a VPN server which is deciding which packet has to be crypted and which not, should also be **the firewall**.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, fundamentally to block whatever leaks beside the VPN.

And if your VPN server has filtering functions, it is the best place to build the firewalling to protect against:

- whatever tries to go outside of the VPN,
- whatever tries to attack the VPN server from the outside and from the inside (and moreover from outside and inside of the VPN).

Everywhere else, this firewalling will:

- cost you another equipment,
- be too late relative to traffic.

Answer (score 1):

A usual case for using firewall is, for example, to add a  packet filters to the Internet interface to allow only VPN traffic to and from the IP address of the VPN server's Internet interface. However, if you read documentation such as ([Common VPN Security Flaws](http://www.nta-monitor.com/files/whitepapers/VPN-Flaws-Whitepaper.pdf)), you will understand that putting a firewall between 2 routers is an  other good security layer for your VPN to have.

Answer (score 1):

A VPN is essentially a way to securely bridge two networks (particularly in the context of your question - often referred to as "LAN-to-LAN" or "site to site" VPN.

A firewall is a device which manages packets passing thought it depending on various criteria. The aim is usually to opacify services "behind" the firewall. There are many more possible usages.

They work together, or each on their own.

- the VPN solves the problem of "how to connect such and such networks though an insecure path (the Internet for instance)
- the firewall solves the problem of "how to make sure that services within a network are not seen outside of thsi network" (again, in the context of your question)

You may use combos of both (Cisco makes them, as wall as many other vendors).

So to answer your question: no, firewalls are not *required* when using VPN, they serve (roughly speaking) different purposes.